# Have a Drag & Drop for Selenium. Trying to convert it to

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this snippet of code here: https://pastebin.com/0vqR77C7

This code allows you to "drag and drop" a file into the browser by basically using these lines

```
# drop a single file
dropzone.drop_files("C:\\temp\\image1.png")
 
# drop two files
dropzone.drop_files(["C:\\temp\\image1.png", "C:\\temp\\image2.png"])
 
# drop a file by offset
dropzone.drop_files("C:\\temp\\image1.png", offsetX=25, offsetY=25)
```

I want to convert this to NodeJS version. How would I go about this?